# Problem with adapter on cursor RecyclerVew

Tags: android, kotlin

I've been following a tutorial that uses a provider to talk to a DB and use an observer to keep a RecyclerView up to date. Its a bit out of date so I've spent a few houres getting it (kind of working).  I got as far as getting it working when there were no records in the DB (I pass null cursor to the RecycleViewAdapter and if this is the case it displays instructinos in the list view).  When I run it I get the instructions even though there are 2 records in DB.

The problem is when I have data it does not seem to update the Recycle view.

In the Fragment, I am setting up the adapter and observer.

So I have set up the adapter in the Fragment class

```
private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskTimerViewModel::class.java] } 
private val mAdapter = CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(null) // null=view with instructions
```

In onCreate set up the observer

```
viewModel.cursor.observe( // New
  this, Observer { cursor -> mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)?.close() }
)
```

and in onViewCreated setup the adapter

```
binding.taskList.adapter = mAdapter // Attach Adapter to Recyclerview
```

Looking at Logcat when I query the DB in AppPrivider I get two rows returned then later on I see the CursorRecyclerView adapter has no records.  This Logcat is from just running the App without interacting with it.  I am expecting to see the records from the database but I just see the instructions (which are displayed when there is no data).

```
AppProviderXX        com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreate
MainActivityXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreate
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onAttach
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreate
TaskTimerViewModelXX com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  init
TaskTimerViewModelXX com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  loadTasks
AppProviderXX        com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  query for uri=content://com.funkytwig.tasktimer.provider/Tasks
AppProviderXX        com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  buildUriMatcher
AppProviderXX        com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  query: 2 rows returned
TaskTimerViewModelXX com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  loadTasks done
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreate done
MainActivityXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreate done
MainActivityXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onStart
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreateView
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onViewCreated
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onViewStateRestored
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onStart
MainActivityXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onResume
MainFragmentXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onResume
CurRecViewAdapterXX  com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  getItemCount: no items so return 1
CurRecViewAdapterXX  com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  swapCursor new & previous cursor unchanged
CurRecViewAdapterXX  com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  getItemCount: no items so return 1
CurRecViewAdapterXX  com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  getItemCount: no items so return 1
CurRecViewAdapterXX  com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreateViewHolder
CurRecViewAdapterXX  com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onBindViewHolder: cursor empty
MainActivityXX       com.funkytwig.takstimer  D  onCreateOptionsMenu
```

Full code at https://github.com/funkytwig/tasktimer/tree/master/app/src/main but I have included what I think are the most relevent classes below.

The code for **MainFragment.kt** is:

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.FragmentMainBinding


private const val TAG = "MainFragmentXX"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass as the default destination in the navigation.
 */
class MainFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null
    private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskTimerViewModel::class.java] } // New
    private val mAdapter = CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(null) // null=view with instructions NEW

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val funct = "onCreate"
        Log.d(TAG, funct)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel.cursor.observe( // New
            this, Observer { cursor -> mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)?.close() }
        )
        Log.d(TAG, "$funct done")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView")
        _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onViewCreated")
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.taskList.layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(context) // Set layout manager to Linear NEW
        binding.taskList.adapter = mAdapter // Attach Adapter to Recyclerview New
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyView")
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

The code for **TaskTimerViewModel.kt** is:

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.app.Application
import android.database.Cursor
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData

private const val TAG = "TaskTimerViewModelXX"

class TaskTimerViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val dbCursor = MutableLiveData<Cursor>()
    val cursor: LiveData<Cursor>
        get() = dbCursor

    init {
        Log.d(TAG, "init")
        loadTasks()
    }

    private fun loadTasks() {
        val funct = "loadTasks"
        Log.d(TAG, funct)
        val projection = arrayOf(
            TasksContract.Columns.TASK_NAME,
            TasksContract.Columns.TASK_DESCRIPTION,
            TasksContract.Columns.TASK_SORT_ORDER
        )
        val sortOrder =
            "${TasksContract.Columns.TASK_SORT_ORDER}, ${TasksContract.Columns.TASK_NAME}"
        val cursor = getApplication<Application>().contentResolver.query(
            TasksContract.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, sortOrder
        )
        dbCursor.postValue(cursor!!) // Update on different thread
        Log.d(TAG, "$funct done")

    }
}
```

code for **CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.tk** is:

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.database.Cursor
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageButton
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.funkytwig.tasktimer.databinding.TaskListItemsBinding

private const val TAG = "CurRecViewAdapterXX"

class TaskViewHolder(private val binding: TaskListItemsBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    val taskListName: TextView = binding.taskListName
    val taskListDescription: TextView = binding.taskListDescription
    val taskListEdit: ImageButton = binding.taskListEdit
    val taskListDelete: ImageButton = binding.taskListDelete
}

class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(private var cursor: Cursor?) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskViewHolder>() {

    // Called by Recyclerview when it needs new view to display
    // viewType allows different types to be shows on different lines of view,
    // to find out more google 'Recyclerview getItemViewType
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TaskViewHolder {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder")
        val viewHolder = TaskListItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return TaskViewHolder(viewHolder)
    }

    // When Recycler view wants new data to be displayed and is providing existing view to be reused
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TaskViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val func = "onBindViewHolder"
        val cursor = cursor // Smart Cast Hack

        if (cursor == null || cursor.count == 0) { // No items in cursor
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: cursor empty")
            holder.taskListName.setText(R.string.instructions_heading)
            holder.taskListDescription.setText(R.string.instructions)
            holder.taskListEdit.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.taskListDelete.visibility = View.GONE
        } else { // Cursor not empty
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: cursor NOT empty")
            if (!cursor.moveToPosition(position)) throw IllegalStateException("Could not move cursor to position $position")
            // Create Task object from data in cursor
            val task = Task(
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.TASK_NAME)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.TASK_DESCRIPTION)),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.TASK_SORT_ORDER))
            )
            // Remember ID is not set in constructor
            task.id = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.Columns.ID))
            holder.taskListName.text = task.name
            holder.taskListDescription.text = task.description
            holder.taskListEdit.visibility = View.VISIBLE // TODO: add onclick
            holder.taskListDelete.visibility = View.VISIBLE // TODO: add onclick
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        val func = "getItemCount"
        val count = cursor?.count
        if (count == 0 || cursor == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: no items so return 1")
            return 1 // So Instructions are displayed if cursor empty
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func: $count items")
            return count!!.toInt()
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swap is a new cursor, returning the old cursor.
     * The returned cursor is *not* closed
     *
     * This allows underlying cursor to be swapped if data changes and we need to re query
     * Should be called when the cursor that the adapter is using is changed.
     * Reruns previous cursor so it can be closed.
     *
     * @param newCursor The new cursor to be used if there was not one.
     * If the given new cursor is the same as the previous set cursor, null is also returned.
     */
    fun swapCursor(newCursor: Cursor?): Cursor? {
        val func = "swapCursor"
        if (newCursor === cursor) return null

        val numItems = itemCount
        val oldCursor = cursor

        if (newCursor != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func new & previous cursor unchanged")
            // notify observer about cursor
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        } else { // cursor has changed
            Log.d(TAG, "$func new & previous cursor different")
            // Notify observer about lack of dataset, all of it from 0 to newItems,
            // i.e. whole range of records has gone
            notifyItemRangeChanged(0, numItems)
        }

        return oldCursor
    }
}
```

And code for **AppProvider.kt** is

```
package com.funkytwig.tasktimer

import android.content.ContentProvider
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.UriMatcher
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log

import androidx.core.content.ContentProviderCompat.requireContext

/**
 * Provider for the TaskTimer app.  This is the only class that knows about [AppDatabase]
 */

private const val TAG = "AppProviderXX"

const val CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.funkytwig.tasktimer.provider" // unique provider name

// The following constants are the integers returned by the UriMatched depending on the Uri.
private const val TASKS = 100
private const val TASKS_ID = 101

private const val TIMINGS = 200
private const val TIMINGS_ID = 201

private const val TASK_DURATIONS = 400
private const val TASK_DURATIONS_ID = 401

val CONTENT_PROVIDER_URI: Uri = Uri.parse("content://$CONTENT_AUTHORITY") // usable outside app

class AppProvider : ContentProvider() {
    private val uriMatcher by lazy { buildUriMatcher() }

    private fun buildUriMatcher(): UriMatcher { // Helps us parse out the table name
        Log.d(TAG, "buildUriMatcher")
        val matcher = UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH) // NO_MATCH if root URi matched

        // com.funkytwig.tasktimer.provider/Tasks
        matcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, TasksContract.TABLE_NAME, TASKS)
        // com.funkytwig.tasktimer.provider/Tasks/ID
        matcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, "${TasksContract.TABLE_NAME}/#", TASKS_ID) // #=number
        matcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME, TIMINGS)
        matcher.addURI(CONTENT_AUTHORITY, "${TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME}/#", TIMINGS_ID)

        return matcher
    }


    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {
        val func = "onCreate"
        Log.d(TAG, func)
        return true // We are creating DB in AppDatabase singleton
    }


    override fun getType(uri: Uri): String? {
        val match = uriMatcher.match(uri)
        Log.d(TAG,"getType match $match")
        return when (match) {
            TASKS -> TasksContract.CONTENT_TYPE
            TASKS_ID -> TasksContract.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            TIMINGS -> TimingsContract.CONTENT_TYPE
            TIMINGS_ID -> TimingsContract.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Unknown Uri: $uri")
        }
    }


    override fun query(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<out String>?, // String array of columns to return
        selection: String?, // WHERE columns
        selectionArgs: Array<out String>?, // Where values for columns
        sortOrder: String? // ORDER BY
    ): Cursor? {
        val func = "query"
        Log.d(TAG, "$func for uri=$uri")
        val match = uriMatcher.match(uri)

        val queryBuilder = SQLiteQueryBuilder()

        when (match) {
            TASKS -> queryBuilder.tables = TasksContract.TABLE_NAME

            TASKS_ID -> {
                queryBuilder.tables = TasksContract.TABLE_NAME
                val taskId = TasksContract.getId(uri)
                Log.d(TAG, "$func: $taskId")
                queryBuilder.appendWhere("${TasksContract.Columns.ID} =")
                queryBuilder.appendWhereEscapeString("$taskId")
            }

            TIMINGS -> queryBuilder.tables = TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME

            TIMINGS_ID -> {
                queryBuilder.tables = TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME
                val timingsId = TimingsContract.getId(uri)
                queryBuilder.appendWhereEscapeString("${TimingsContract.Columns.ID} = $timingsId")
                queryBuilder.appendWhere("${TimingsContract.Columns.ID} =")
                queryBuilder.appendWhereEscapeString("$timingsId")
            }

            else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Unknown URI: $uri")
        }

        val context = requireContext(this) // Get NotNull context for ContentProvider
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).readableDatabase
        val cursor =
            queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder)
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: ${cursor.count} rows returned") // TODO remove this line
        return cursor
    }


    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
        // accepts a uri and return uri with ID added
        val func = "insert"
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, func)
            logValues(values)
        }
        if (values == null) throw IllegalAccessException("$func ContentValues can not be null")

        val recordId: Long
        val returnUri: Uri

        val context = requireContext(this) // Get NotNull context for ContentProvider
        // was told not to do this as its is 'slow' but that's only if thee is a problem (invalid Uri)
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).writableDatabase

        // writableDatabase and readableDatabase slow so do not call if invalid Uri
        val match = uriMatcher.match(uri)
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: match=$match for uri=$uri")
        when (match) {
            TASKS -> {
                recordId = db.insert(TasksContract.TABLE_NAME, null, values)
                if (recordId != -1L)
                    returnUri = TasksContract.buildUriFromId(recordId)
                else throw IllegalAccessException("Failed to insert $uri")
            }
            TIMINGS -> {
                recordId = db.insert(TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME, null, values)
                if (recordId != -1L)
                    returnUri = TimingsContract.buildUriFromId(recordId)
                else throw IllegalAccessException("Failed to insert $uri")
            }
            else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Unknown Uri: $uri")
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Created record Uri $returnUri")
        return returnUri
    }


    override fun update(
        uri: Uri,
        values: ContentValues?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<out String>?
    ): Int {
        val func = "update"
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$func $uri")
            logValues(values)
        }

        if (values == null) throw IllegalAccessException("$func ContentValues can not be null")

        val count: Int
        var selectionCriteria: String

        val context = requireContext(this) // Get NotNull context for ContentProvider
        // was told not to do this as its is 'slow' but that's only if thee is a problem (invalid Uri)
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).writableDatabase

        val match = uriMatcher.match(uri)
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: match=$match for uri=$uri")
        when (match) {
            TASKS -> // Whole table + possible selection
                count = db.update(TasksContract.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs)
            TASKS_ID -> { // single ID + possible selection
                val id = TasksContract.getId(uri)
                selectionCriteria = "${TasksContract.Columns.ID} = $id"
                if (selection != null && selection.isNotEmpty()) selectionCriteria += " AND ($selection)"
                count =
                    db.update(TasksContract.TABLE_NAME, values, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs)
            }
            TIMINGS ->  // Whole table + possible selection
                count = db.update(TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs)
            TIMINGS_ID -> { // single ID + possible selection
                val id = TimingsContract.getId(uri)
                selectionCriteria = "${TimingsContract.Columns.ID} = $id"
                if (selection != null && selection.isNotEmpty()) selectionCriteria += " AND ($selection)"
                count =
                    db.update(TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME, values, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Unknown Uri: $uri")
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Created record Uri $uri Count $count")
        return count
    }


    override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int {
        val func = "delete"
        Log.d(TAG, func)

        val count: Int
        var selectionCriteria: String

        val context = requireContext(this) // Get NotNull context for ContentProvider
        // was told not to do this as its is 'slow' but that's only if thee is a problem (invalid Uri)
        val db = AppDatabase.getInstance(context).writableDatabase

        val match = uriMatcher.match(uri)
        Log.d(TAG, "$func: match=$match for uri=$uri")
        when (match) {
            TASKS ->  // Whole table + possible selection
                count = db.delete(TasksContract.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs)
            TASKS_ID -> { // single ID + possible selection
                val id = TasksContract.getId(uri)
                selectionCriteria = "${TasksContract.Columns.ID} = $id"
                if (selection != null && selection.isNotEmpty()) selectionCriteria += " AND ($selection)"
                count = db.delete(TasksContract.TABLE_NAME, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs)
            }
            TIMINGS ->  // Whole table + possible selection
                count = db.delete(TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs)
            TIMINGS_ID -> { // single ID + possible selection
                val id = TimingsContract.getId(uri)
                selectionCriteria = "${TimingsContract.Columns.ID} = $id"
                if (selection != null && selection.isNotEmpty()) selectionCriteria += " AND ($selection)"
                count = db.delete(TimingsContract.TABLE_NAME, selectionCriteria, selectionArgs)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalAccessException("Unknown Uri: $uri")
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Delete record Uri $uri Count $count")
        return count
    }

    private fun logValues(values: ContentValues?) {
        for (key in values!!.keySet()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "logValues:$key=${values.get(key)}")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `swapCursor` method you are not assigning the `newCursor` to `this.cursor`. So you never use the new cursor in the adapter.